# Values from database based on two combo boxes into text box

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to put a value based on two cascading combo boxes from a  database table into a text box. Filling the two cascading  combo boxes works. However when I try to put the result in the text box I run into trouble. I am using the following code :

```
Private Sub CmbPlaasnaam_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmbPlaasnaam.SelectedIndexChanged

    If CmbAliasnaam.SelectedIndex > -1 AndAlso CmbPlaasnaam.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
        Dim aliasnaam As String =
            CmbAliasnaam.Items(CmbAliasnaam.SelectedIndex).ToString
        Dim plaasnaam As String =
            CmbPlaasnaam.Items(CmbPlaasnaam.SelectedIndex).ToString

        Dim qry = From zc As SkeduleringsDatabasis6DataSet.OesskattingsRow In SkeduleringsDatabasis6DataSet.Oesskattings
                  Where zc.Aliasnaam = aliasnaam AndAlso
                      zc.Plaasnaam = plaasnaam
                  Select zc.Plaasnommer


        txtPlaasnommer.Text = zc.plaasnommer

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: _"I run into trouble"_ is not a problem description. What happened?

Comment: Apologies, my bad. I got the following error message : 
Error BC30451 'zc' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. The eror occurred at the line : txt.Plaasnommer.Text =zc.plaasnommer.

Comment: There are alternates to using events as you are, if you setup relationships between the master and detail data source this allows the bindings to do all the work for you. If you would like I can write this up in a demo using SQL-Server and an existing MSDN code sample I can modify to show how this is done. The start code is below (uses listboxes but works the same for combo boxes) https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/-Detail-for-ListBoxs-and-d896b5ed?redir=0

Answer (score 0):

zc on your last line does not exists
you should use qry variable 
like:

```
    if qry.Count>0 Then
txtPlaasnommer.Text = qry.first
End If
```

zc is the inner linq variable and qry is the result that you should use

Answer (score 0):

Use this line :

```
txtPlaasnommer.Text = qry.FirstOrDefault.ToString()
```